# Disabling Audio Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

When creating an AS3 project and adding audio what I usually do is drag the audio I want to use (for a game menu for example) and when I want to stop the audio I enter

`SoundMixer.stopAll();`

I do this because if I say go to the about game frame in this menu then I will have the audio, but if I come back to the main frame where I originally had the music it sorta doubles in and the two different timings of the music are playing at the same time.How do I stop this without having to disable the audio when I change frame?

Comment: You'd be better off playing your music via code, so you can check to see it's already playing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these cases, it is easier to start and stop the sound directly via code. First, right click the sound clip in your Library panel, and select Properties. In the ActionScript tab, check "Export for ActionScript", and give it a class name of, say, Music. Then, to play and stop this clip, you can use this code:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
// create the music Sound object so that we can start playing
var music : Sound = new Music();
var musicChannel : SoundChannel;

// play the music
// the play() method returns a SoundChannel,
// which you can later use to stop the music
// notice that we first check to make sure musicChannel is null
// if it isn't null, music is already playing, so don't play it twice
if(musicChannel != null) musicChannel = music.play();

// when you switch screens, stop the music
// clear out the channel, so that we know that it is safe to start the music again
musicChannel.stop();
musicChannel = null;
```

Alternatively, if you play music and sounds by placing them on the timeline, you can stop it by using the Sync setting of the frame. On the timeline, create a keyframe where you switch screens and want the music to stop playing. Select that frame, and drag the sound clip you want to stop onto that frame. In the Properties panel, change the Sync option to Stop. This will cause only the selected sound to stop playing.

Yet another method is to create an empty MovieClip with the sound placed inside of it. Change the Sync setting to Stream, and pad the clip out with empty frames so that it will play the entire clip. Then, if you place this clip on your main menu screen, then it will only play during the main menu. Stream sounds only play the sound for as long as the MovieClip exists and is playing. Compare this to normal Event sounds, which will play the entire sound regardless.

The latter methods are more old-school and movie-centric. If you are programming a game, it would be more appropriate to use the former method to give you more control of the audio in code.